# Reading complex JSON object from jQuery AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a web service that returns a JSON object that I'm trying to pull in using an AJAX request via jQuery. Here is the call:

```
function CallService() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Home/CallJSON",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data["Data"]["?xml"].divisions.Section1[0].name);
        alert("Success");
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert("Error" + data.responseText);
    }
});

}
```

Here is the JSON output received from the web service request:

```
{"ContentEncoding":null,"ContentType":null,"Data":"
{\"?xml\":
    {\"@version\":\"1.0\",\"@encoding\":\"utf-8\",\"@standalone\":\"yes\"},
    \"divisions\":
        {\"requestContact\":\"name@email.com, name2@email.com\",
        \"customize\":\"FOLDER1/FILE1.htm\",
        \"Section1\":[
            {\"@id\":\"1\",
            \"name\":\"Name Here\",
            \"Section2\":
                {\"@id\":\"1\",
                \"name\":\"Name Here2\",
                \"Section3\":
                    {\"@id\":\"1\",
                    \"name\":\"Name Here3\",
                    \"Section4\":[
                        {\"@id\":\"1\",
                        \"name\":\"Name Here4\",
                        \"#comment\":[],
                        \"display\":[
                            {\"@id\":\"1\",
                            \"name\":\"Display Name1\",
                            \"code\":\"500001\"},

                            {\"@id\":\"2\",
                            \"name\":\"Display Name2\",
                            \"code\":\"500023\"}
                        ]}
                    ]}
                }
            }]
        }
},
"JsonRequestBehavior":1,"MaxJsonLength":null,"RecursionLimit":null}
```

**The Problem**

I'm currently unable to pull anything out of the JSON object. If you look at my ajax request, if I understand the structure of this JSON object I believe I'm calling everything correctly to pull the "name" element from the first "Section1" item:

```
data["Data"]["?xml"].divisions.Section1[0].name
```

But I continually get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'divisions' of undefined

Clearly, I'm missing something here. Any takers?

**EDIT**
To explain further, I'm accessing a web service that I do not have access into. The person that has access to it added an ability to specify a JSON request by adding "?type=json" as a parameter on the requesting URL. I built an intermediary web service that is local to my AJAX call to remove the cross-domain issue that would otherwise present itself.

Here is my intermediary back-end web service:

```
    public JsonResult CallJSON()
    {
        string requestURL = "https://www.someurlhere.com/service.ashx?type=json";

        WebRequest webReq = WebRequest.Create(requestURL);
        webReq.Method = "GET";

        WebResponse webRes = webReq.GetResponse();
        Stream reqStream = webRes.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(reqStream);
        string finalResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();

        JsonResult jsonResponse = new JsonResult();
        jsonResponse.Data = finalResponse;

        return Json(jsonResponse, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: This XML as per my understanding not JSON. It would be better if use `dataType: "XML",`

Comment: Could you paste the webservice code that is returning that JSON? the problem relays that you are not being able to target ['?xml']

Comment: I'm accessing a web service that originally only gave output for XML, but was recently given the ability to output JSON, which essentially is the exact same output as XML just in a JSON object. The idea was JSON is supposed to be easier to work with than XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `data.Data` property contains a json string, you'll need to decode it.

```
alert($.parseJSON(data["Data"])["?xml"].divisions.Section1[0].name)
```

Comment: It's all the double escaped quotes. Do you have control of the script that is returning this data?

Comment: So that you better understand...the web service is cross domain out of my control. On my side, I'm making a back-end call to the web service to avoid the typical cross-domain issue and returning the JSON object to the local AJAX call. So I have control at the intermediary layer, but not the source.

Comment: Maybe I'm just better off calling the XML version of the service and keeping at that?

Comment: What are you doing in the intermediary stage? it looks like you're converting the xml into JSON, and then double encoding the json which is where the problem is coming from. You likely will be better off leaving it in xml format, but it should be possible to just stop double encoding it.

Comment: Please see the edit to my question above for intermediary code

Comment: I'm not familiar with the language you're using, but ideally you'll want to return the string that is being returned from the service directly, you shouldn't need to encode it as json as it should already be json.

Comment: To verify I ran Fiddler to see the response...on the responding side, I'm seeing:  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8, when I click the JSON tab, it is blank, which makes me wonder if it is not properly being returned as JSON

Comment: I think I'm just going to go the XML route as I don't have full confidence that the primary service was setup properly. Thanks for all of your help!